# Unable to retrieve the image from SDCard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-sdcard, android-image

```
Drawable image = Drawable.createFromPath(newImagepath);
defective_image.setBackgroundDrawable(image);
```

The image is stored in the newImagePath variable which is a String. The above throws an outOfMemory Exception.

I also tried retrieving the image into a Bitmap object.

```
Bitmap bitmapImg= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(newImagepath);
```

In the above case the bitmapImg is Null. (Without any exception)

However if it is retrieved as a file, it's successful. This doesn't serve my purpose because I want this image to be the background of a RelativeLayout.

```
File imageFile = new File(newImagepath);
String imgPath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

The imgPath is the same as the newImagePath, concluding the path is not wrong. I also verified the image's existence in the SDCard.

This image was captured from the device's camera. This code is working on the emulator successfully. When debugged on the device the above said faults were noticed. 
I also tried:-

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
```

Comment: Do you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in your manifest?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

I have WRITE. Doesn't that apply I am allwoed to read as well? And more over I can read it into a File object. Only the Bitmap or the Drawable object is creating a problem.

Comment: Since the retrieval of the image into the Drawable object threw an OutOfMemory exception, I thought it was a size of the image related issue?

Comment: WRITE permission includes READ, so all seem ok here. Did you try other bitmap file?

Comment: Mainly the images taken from the camera is creating a problem. Any other image is not creating an issue.

I actually have to load the image in two places:-
1) Image View: I retreived the file using the URI, i.e., file:///mnt/sdcard/shopfloor/img1. The ImageView can be set using this URI. This is working fine.
2) Relative Lyout: This layout has to be set with the image as the background. I cannot do so using the URI. Which is why I had to cut short the URI into a path /sdcard/shopfloor/img1. This cannot be loaded into the Drawable or the Bitmap object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a memory issue. So I suggest to decode bitmap size with the option

```
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
```

then getting the size of this bitmap by looking at fields (don't try to use bitmap : it will be null) :

```
options.outWidth;
options.outHeight;
```

Then creating a scaled bitmap (depending on the screen dimension). To do this, you can look at

```
BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use a [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String%29) to decode the Image from the file-path:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
jpgView.setImageDrawable(bitmap);
```